# Find the largest sum of the maximal, compatible, values of two sorted arrays in sub quadratic time

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Say I have two sorted lists like so:

- a = [13, 7, 5, 3, 2, ..., 0]
- b = [16, 12, 8, 4, ..., 1]

Also I have a function:

```
IsValid(x,y):
```

Which returns true if x and y are compatible.  Compatibility completely arbitrary, except the value 0 is valid with any other number.

So how would i find the two numbers in a and b such that yield the greatest sum given they are both IsValid.  Ie find the greatest valid sum.

Here is my current alg in Python

```
def FindBest(a, b):
isDone = False
aChecked =[]
bChecked = []
aPossible = []
aIndex = 0
bPossible = []
bIndex = 0
posResult = []



#initialize
try:
    aPossible= (a[aIndex])
    aIndex+=1
    bPossible=(b[bIndex])
    bIndex+=1
except:
    print "Why did you run this on an empty list?"
    return

while not isDone:
    posResult = []


    if(len(aPossible)>0):
        for b in bChecked:
            if(IsValid(aPossible,b)):
                posResult.append(aPossible+b)
                isDone = True


    if len(bPossible)>0:
        for a in aChecked:
            if(IsValid(a,bPossible)):
                posResult.append(a+bPossible)
                isDone = True

    #compare the first two possibles
    if(IsValid(aPossible,bPossible)):
                posResult.append(aPossible+bPossible)
                isDone = True

    if(len(aPossible) > 0):
        aChecked.append(bPossible)
    if(len(bPossible) >0):
        bChecked.append(bPossible)

    if(aIndex<len(a)):
        aPossible= (a[aIndex])
        aIndex+=1
    if(bIndex<len(b)):
        bPossible =(b[bIndex])
        bIndex+=1
    if len(a)==len(aChecked) and len(b) == len(bChecked):
        print "none found"
        isDone = True

return posResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But as others has pointed out, the worst case of this is `O(n*n)` where `n` is the size of each list.

For a worst case example, consider `a = [9,8,7,0]` and `b = [4,3,2,1]` where there are no compatible pairs other than `(0,4),(0,3),(0,2),(0,1)`.

Let's optimistically assume that you somehow checked and found these four pair first.
So you remembered that the pair `(0,4)` is the current-best answer.
You would still need to check all the pairs that are larger than size four to make sure that `(0,4)` really is the best answer.
To list those pairs:

```
(9,4)
(9,3) (8,4)
(9,2) (8,3) (7,4)
(9,1) (8,2) (7,3)
```

And the number of these pairs are growing O(n*n).

So it is impossible to deduce a **sub** quadratic time algorithm.
[Because I assume the best algorithm can be implemented, that algorithm still takes at least O(n*n) on some cases]

Maybe you left out some more information from your question?

Comment: No, but thanks for your input.

Yeah Its probibly worst case O(n^2).

In that case i believe my alg produces fast, but possibly inaccurite results, which is acceptable.